# License plate probability question

Tags: probability

Alaska license plates have two letters followed by three numbers. What is the probability that a randomly chosen license plate will have an NC with the number ending in a 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$p = (1/26) \cdot (1/26) \cdot (1/10)$$